# Xcode build framework normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, arm64

Im' facing this issue
normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler

When i tried to make a framework only for architecture simulators arm 64

```
 xcodebuild archive \
  -workspace Project.xcworkspace\
  -scheme "myFramework" \
  -sdk iphonesimulator \
  -archivePath "$BUILD_PATH/myFramework/ios_simulators64.xcarchive" \
  -arch arm64
  BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES\
  BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode 2>&1\
  SKIP_INSTALL=NO
```

this is the error :

The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Users/Blabla/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BlueStackSDK-cjunsfsbsoawxlbizlbpxpqzfknv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/BlueStackLocationAdapter/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/BlueStackSDK.build/Release-iphonesimulator/BlueStackLocationAdapter.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MAdvertiseLocationAdapter.o /Users/Blabla/Documents/Projects/MAdvertise/Blue\ Stack\ New\ Hope/BlueStackSDK/Adapters/BlueStackLocationAdapter/MAdvertiseLocationAdapter.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Also ,

error:
unsupported Swift architecture
#error unsupported Swift architecture

any help?
thank you

Comment: You forgot to tell us what your issue is.